# Jordan normal form which depends on parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Find the values of the parameter $a\in\Bbb R$ for which the Jordan normal form of $$M=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\0&a-2&4\\0&-1&a+2\end{pmatrix}$$ contains a Jordan block of order $2$.

I calculated the characteristic polynomial, algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity. However I obtain that geometric multiplicity is always one compared to algebraic multiplicity of 2, so I wanted to check.

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: I calculated the characteristic polynomial, algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity. However I obtain that geometric multiplicity is always one compared to algebraic multiplicity of 2, so I wanted to check.

Comment: @oggyvukovich good.  Well, for future reference, note that you should [provide context when asking a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We obtain a characteristic polynomial of 
$$
(x-1)(x^2 - 2ax + a^2) = (x-1)(x-a)^2
$$
When $a \neq 1$, we note that the rank of $M - aI$ is $2$ (that is, $a$ has a geometric multiplicity of $1$), indicating that the Jordan form of $M$ has a block of size $2$ associated with $a$.

However, in the case that $a = 1$, we find that $M - I$ has a rank of $2$ (that is, $a = 1$ has a geometric multiplicity of $1$), indicating that the Jordan form of $M$ consists of one block of **size 3**.

So, the answer: $a \neq 1$.